# Tautological implication question.

Tags: logic

I had this question in the homework and i don't get why the answer is right.

$B, A \rightarrow B \vDash_{TAUT} A\ $ is not valid.

If there exists a state $v$ such that $v(A) = f$ and $v(B) = t$ then both $B$ and $A \rightarrow B$ are satisfied while $A$ is not. Take for example, $A$ to be $\bot$ and $B$ to be $\top$.

That was the answer for the homework. But i could take $A$ to be true and $B$ to be also true so $ A \rightarrow B $ is true. Isn't that right ?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems unclear to me - not the question you asked, the question they asked you ;-)

I think the reasoning they are asking about is the following:

- given $B$ and $A\to B$, we conclude $A$.

This is an invalid deduction for the reasons given in the answer.

I don't know what format you are using in your studies but for me
$$B\,,\ A\to B\quad\hbox{therefore}\quad A$$
would make more sense than
$$B\,,\ A\to B\quad\hbox{and}\quad A\ .$$

Comment: Actually may be i wrote it in a wrong way. It ask about tautological implication. There is weird symbol for that i could't write so i wrote "and".

Comment: The symbol wasn't $\vdash$ was it?

Comment: No it wasn't that. It's not metaproving.

Comment: Perhaps you can find it on [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and post it?

Comment: $ \models $ and "taut" written as a subscript

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't match how I use these symbols - I guess your instructors are doing it differently.  All the same I suspect that the issue is pretty much as I suggested in my answer, even if the approach is different.

Comment: Is the symbol : $\vDash_{TAUT}$ ? If so it means "tautologically implies".

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the right symbol to be used is : $\vDash_{TAUT}$; it means "tautologically implies" : if so, you attempted solution is not the right one.

We want to prove that

> $B,A \rightarrow B \vDash_{TAUT} A$ is not valid, i.e. $B,A \rightarrow B \nvDash_{TAUT} A$

To show this we need to find a *valuation* $v$ such that both $B$ and $A \rightarrow B$ are satisfied while $A$ is not.

If we remeber the truth-functional definition of $\rightarrow$, we have that when $A$ is *false* and $B$ is *true*, then $A \rightarrow B$ is *true*.

So, our valuation $v$ must be defined as :

> $v(A) = f$ and $v(B) = t$.

With this $v$ we have that $v(B)=v(A \rightarrow B)=t$ and $v(A)=f$, so that :

> $B,A \rightarrow B \nvDash_{TAUT} A$.

Comment: But we can make $ v(A) = t \ and\  v(B) = t \ so\  v(A \rightarrow B) = t $. Now this could be valid. Right ?

Comment: **NO.** The definition of *validity* (the tautological one is only restricted to propositional logic, but the general properties are the same) is : "for all interpretations (or valuations) that make true all the premises, the consequence is also true". So, to show *validity* uou must "check" all the possibilities; in order to check "invalidity", instead, a single counter-example suffices.